# replace value in datafrme if another value is empty

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
x = data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
               subgroup = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4.1, 4.2),
               type = c("good", 'good', 'bad', 'bad', 'good', 'bad', 'bad', 'good', 'good', '')
)
```

I want to replace subgroup value to "A" if type is empty.so exceted output is:

```
x = data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
               subgroup = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4.1, "A"),
               type = c("good", 'good', 'bad', 'bad', 'good', 'bad', 'bad', 'good', 'good', '')
)
```

I tried this:

```
if (x$type = '') {
  x$subgroup = "A"
}
```

But it didnt work. How could i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base `R` you can simply choose the values that match your condition (subgroup value in row where type is empty) and then replace them:

```
x$subgroup[x$type == ""] <- "A"
x
#>    group subgroup type
#> 1      1      1.1 good
#> 2      1      1.2 good
#> 3      1      1.3  bad
#> 4      2      2.1  bad
#> 5      2      2.2 good
#> 6      3      3.1  bad
#> 7      3      3.2  bad
#> 8      3      3.3 good
#> 9      4      4.1 good
#> 10     4        A
```

Alternativly, you can use `dplyr`/tidyverse and an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  mutate(subgroup = ifelse(test = type == "", yes = "A", no = subgroup))
#>    group subgroup type
#> 1      1      1.1 good
#> 2      1      1.2 good
#> 3      1      1.3  bad
#> 4      2      2.1  bad
#> 5      2      2.2 good
#> 6      3      3.1  bad
#> 7      3      3.2  bad
#> 8      3      3.3 good
#> 9      4      4.1 good
#> 10     4        A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

- using `ifelse`

```
x <- within(x,subgroup <- ifelse(type=="","A",subgroup))
```

- using `replace`

```
x <- within(x,subgroup <- replace(subgroup,type=="","A"))
```

or

```
x <- within(x,subgroup <- replace(subgroup,nchar(as.character(type))==0,"A"))
```

such that

```
> x
   group subgroup type
1      1      1.1 good
2      1      1.2 good
3      1      1.3  bad
4      2      2.1  bad
5      2      2.2 good
6      3      3.1  bad
7      3      3.2  bad
8      3      3.3 good
9      4      4.1 good
10     4        A
```